# Code to login not working

Tags: java

could anyone help me with figuring out why this code isn't working? It's supposed to log into HTS, but it doesn't work. It's not giving me any error messages or anything, just no result at all. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Login {

private static URL URLObj;
private static URLConnection connect;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        URLObj = new URL("http://www.hackthissite.org/user/login");
        connect = URLObj.openConnection();
        connect.addRequestProperty("REFERER", "http://www.hackthissite.org");
        connect.setDoOutput(true);

    }
    catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        System.out.println("The URL specified was unable to be parsed or uses an invalid protocol. Please try again.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("An exception occurred. " + ex.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }

    try {
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connect.getOutputStream()));
        writer.write("username=BrandonHeat&password=**********&btn_submit=Login");
        writer.close();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));

        String lineRead = "";

        while ((lineRead = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(lineRead);
        }

        reader.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("There was an error reading or writing to the URL: " + ex.getMessage());
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

i'm just guessing, but the documentation for URLConnection indicates that you must connect after having set the parameters :

> 1.The connection object is created by invoking the openConnection method on
>   a URL.
>   2.The setup parameters and general request properties are manipulated.
>   3.The actual connection to the remote object is made, using the connect
>   method.
>   4.The remote object becomes available. The header fields and the contents of
>   the remote object can be accessed.
>   ...
>   The following methods are used to
>   access the header fields and the
>   contents after the connection is made
>   to the remote object:
>
> - getContent
> - getHeaderField
> - getInputStream
> - getOutputStream

Edit :
can't you open the URL with you parameters in the URL (ie http://www.hackthissite.org/user/login?username=BrandonHeat&password=xxxxx&btn_submit=Login), or setted as header  ?

also, after the connect(), what do you get if you do a getContent() ?

Edit : there is a description of the process [here](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html).

Regards
Guillaume

Comment: Tried it that way as well, still no result :(

Comment: If I open the URL with the parameters(even normally in the browser), I get a message "Please use the login form to the right to login to HackThisSite." getContent() is null;

Comment: OK, after some tampering I finally made it connect and now I get the page, however I am not sure whether I just connect to the page or login as well. I've added a new part to the code that moves to another page of the site after it logs in, but I get a "You need to be logged in" error, and I am not sure whether this is because I didn't log in properly in the first place, or because I'm not passing in all the necessary data. I am passing a cookie with the session id(PHPSESSID), is there anything else I need to add(or any way to checked if I've really logged in on the first page)?

Comment: Sorry, i'm really not knowledgeable on http process. For me you are not connected, but, as i said, this is only wild guess. Perhaps you could use some navigator plugin to check the parameters (if Firebug, or the IE equivalent) ? There coud be a hidden param that you need to send with the others. Then check the link given in my response above, as there are some info on the subject. Sorry not to be able to help more